# mod rewrite +d error

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm using this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(html|php)$ [OR]
RewriteCond -d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And if i try to access a site afflected by the rule i get an 500 Server Error.

My logs say:

> [Fri Dec 17 13:40:43 2010] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '-d'

If i access something like that:

> http://localhost/icon/help.png

There is no problem

Can someone help me please?

Comment: RewriteCond needs two parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewriteCond` needs to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Now i get: 
[Fri Dec 17 13:46:41 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: @Philipp that is because you've built an infinite loop: index.php gets redirected too. If you want to rewrite URLs for files that don't exist, use `-f` instead of `-d`

Comment: @Philipp `-d` = is existing directory `-f` = is existing file `-s` = is existing symbolic link

Comment: well if i use -f i get 
[Fri Dec 17 13:52:04 2010] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '-f' :x  i want to forward files with .html and .php and folders eg www.example.com/folder => www.example.com/index.php?s=folder

Comment: @Philipp show the entire line you are using. You are using `REQUEST_FILENAME`, right?

Comment: oh sorry, did that syntax error again^^ i get 
[Fri Dec 17 13:56:03 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace. again with -f

Comment: @Philipp ahh quatsch. You need to use `!-f` of course to negate the condition. My fault, didn't notice that

Comment: @Philipp try prepending `!`, see my comment above

Comment: get that error again ): [Fri Dec 17 14:00:02 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
i updated my pastebin file!

Comment: @Philip index.php exists? Can you remove the `[OR]`? I don't think it's needed

Comment: yap its here. i removed [OR] now its okay :D THANK YOU but what does [OR] mean? : x

Comment: No problem. Well, OR means OR :) It applied the condition when the extension was php / html OR when the requested file didn't exist. Which had to cause an endless loop for index.php

Comment: now the .htaccess doesnt affect directorys :x http://localhost/index doesn't foreward

Comment: @Philipp yeah, that's what the rule says - it applies only to php and html files. If you want it to apply to *all* file types, remove the first condition and add a line containing `!-d`

Comment: but it only should foreward .php, .html and folders :D i dont want the images to be affected.

Comment: @Philipp then you'll need to expand the file type regex to match URLs with no dots in them. I'm not regex literate enough to write that out without experimenting, but you can ask a new question, should be easy enough to answer

Comment: @Pekka `-l` is a symlink, `-s` is the same as `-f` where the file is not 0 bytes.